# Does registerReceiver survive reboot?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have registered some BroadcastReceiver dynamically using Context.registerReceiver() (e.g. for Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON). Does it survive reboot? I mean do I need after rebooting call registerReceiver() again?

Comment: Yes you do need to register again. Anyway you can just try and see.

Comment: @m0skit0 So there is no difference between register it dynamically or via AndroidManifest, correct?

Comment: In your question context, no, there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

- If you registered your broadcastreceiver dynamically (programmatically), you would need to restart your application and register it again.
- If you registered your broadcastreceiver  via the manifest and that the manifest contains the permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

and add the intent filter to your receiver, on reboot, your broadcastreceiver should be up and running

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for info (search for  ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED )